# Inserting Current Date as default in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
st.executeUpdate("insert into groupperformance (Date,Gid,GName) values('"+yourDate+"',select Gid,GroupName from grouping)");
```

I use the above query for insert table values.In this table variable yourDate having the Current system Date.And I copy the data's from the table grouping.With out yourDate variable query works fine and inserting values from grouping table to groupperformance table.What can I do for insert current date as default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
st.executeUpdate( 
  "insert into groupperformance (Date,Gid,GName) 
          select '" + yourDate + "', Gid,GroupName from grouping" 
);
```

But, make sure that `yourDate` string is in valid MySQL date format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

And, if you want to insert current date from the database server, you can use `now()` or `curdate()` instead of your selected date.

```
st.executeUpdate( 
  "insert into groupperformance (Date,Gid,GName) 
          select curdate(), Gid,GroupName from grouping" 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentDateTime`, which will return `2008-11-11 12:45:34.243`

OR
something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
OrderId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
ProductName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
OrderDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql's `NOW()` function:

```
st.executeUpdate("insert into groupperformance (Date,Gid,GName) values(NOW(),select Gid,GroupName from grouping)");
```

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you can use `now()` to add the current date in the table

Here is an example how its done

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/080d7f